# Max size of a cyclic graph with conditional edges

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

We have a directed cyclic graph, with some of the edges conditioned on a binary variable, and we need to find the variable assignment that results in the largest graph size (the sum of visited node sizes).

- There could be `k` such variables, and the same variable may reappear multiple times within the graph.
- The variables are independent of each other.

---

1. What are the possible ways to solve this problem efficiently?
2. What does the complexity depend on?
3. What would be an efficient way to sample graph sizes from the space of all possible variable assignments? (with the goal of understanding the distribution)
4. What are known algorithms / graph theory concepts that could be related to this problem?

---

Attached is an example graph and the resulting decision tree that enumerates all the possibilities. The numbers represent node size. The max assignment in this case is [A=false, B=false, C=true], which includes nodes 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9 for the total size of 41.

[image: Graph]
[image: Decision Tree]

Comment: can you please specify a little more how you define graph size? The number of nodes that are reachable from node 1? The maximum number of connected nodes?

Comment: Graph size is the sum of all node sizes which were visited (starting from a fixed set of roots)

Comment: What is the stopping criterion? From your example, it seems that the graph may still contain cycles even after having assigned a value to your variables.

Comment: This problem can be reduced to a **Constraint Optimization Problem** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization#Constraint_optimization_problems. Note that this is an NP-hard problem, so a complete solution will have exponential runtime (relative to K). Assuming you don't have negative nodes, you can easily find the optimal assignment with the **Branch and Bound** algorithm - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound.